# How to import Gson with makefile

Tags: java, makefile, gson

I have the following folder structure:

```
l_append
--LogAppend.java
--User.java
l_read
--LogRead.java
makefile
gson.jar
```

the makefile looks like:

```
LIBRARY_PATHS = gson.jar


CLASS_FILES = l_append/LogAppend.class l_append/User.class l_read/LogRead.class

Default: $(CLASS_FILES) create_bin

%.class: %.java
    $(JC) -cp .:$(LIBRARY_PATHS) $<

create_bin:
    jar -cvmf MANIFEST_LA.MF logappend.jar  l_append/LogAppend.class
    cat stub.sh logappend.jar > logappend && chmod +x logappend

    jar -cvmf MANIFEST_LR.MF logread.jar l_read/LogRead.class
    cat stub.sh logread.jar > logread && chmod +x logread

clean:
    $(RM)  l_read/*.class l_append/*.class log*
```

The LogAppend.java

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
....
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

After I run the make command and want to use the LogAppend I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
        at l_append.LogAppend.writeToLog(LogAppend.java:165)
        at l_append.LogAppend.main(LogAppend.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
```

Any suggestions what I could try?

Comment: what command do you use to execute the jar?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by “want to use the LogAppend”? Are you including gson.jar on the classpath when you run it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why a makefile instead of a build tool for Java, like Maven or Gradle?

Comment: I use java l_append.LogAppend to execute. I include gson in the classpath when running the makefile. Isn't that enough? And the makefile is a requierement for that project.